# pandas.to_datetime() returning different dtypes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

Why does the code below gives rise to the following error
`UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')`?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['2022-01-01'], columns=['start'])
df1['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['start'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(['2023-01-01'], columns=['end'])
df2['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['end'])

df2 - df1
```

Even though I can see that both arguments are showing `datetime64[ns]`:

```
print(df1.loc[0])
start   2022-01-01
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]

print(df2.loc[0])
end   2023-01-01
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subtract first dataframe from second. If you want to get
difference between date in dataframes, you need:

```
df2['end'] - df1['start']
```

Comment: Of course, the column names are different, D'oh!